# Regex text extraction

Tags: regex, excel, extract

I'm trying to use SEO Tools for Excel to extract from the following line:

"productLineCategories":"product abc"

Want to extract just:  product abc   (no quotes or semicolons)

Using productLineCategories(.*)  emits the full "productLineCategories":"product abc"

How can I extract just the value?

Comment: Try `=RegexpIsFind(A2,"(?<=productLineCategories"":"")[^""]+",1)`

Answer (score 1):

Basic regex:

```
"productLineCategories":"([^"]*)"
```

Not familiar with SEO tools, but according to doc `=RegexpIsFind` returns an array of capture groups. With this regex you'll find the second string in the first capture group.

Regards